# How does DataTables row-selector work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datatables

I have a datatable with a number of rows:

```
var table = $('#mytable').DataTable(...)
```

And I'm trying to find the rows that contain `<a>`'s with specific data values.

From the documentation, I'd expect is that `table.rows('<magic row-selector>')` to work, for some value of  `<magic row-selector>`. But even the simplest selectors don't seem to work the way I'd expect them to.

The docs say that if I pass a string to rows(), it is treated as a JQuery selector operating on the the `<tr>` elements.

http://datatables.net/reference/type/row-selector

Now I know for certain that each of these rows contains a number of 's - I can see them in the debugger if I examine the outerHTML of the elements returned by table.rows.nodes(). So I'd expect that this would return all rows:

```
table.rows('a')
```

But it returns none.

What am I not understanding?

What selector should I use, to find all of the rows that contain `<a>`'s with a specified value for a data attribute?

### edited in response to answer

davidkonrad's answer provides some help - I need to pass a jQuery selector object, rather than a string.

Unfortunately, it seems that I need to construct the jQuery selector object before I define the table. I'm not sure I understand why, it seems an unreasonable restriction, but playing around with his fiddle, I did see differences in the rows returned by table.rows(selector) between when I defined the selector before or after I initialized the table.

In my case, then, that makes this approach unusable, because what I'm trying to do is to remove rows that have certain values set in data attributes. There is no way for me to know what values the user might have selected before I construct the table.

Comment: Could you try to use jQuery object http://datatables.net/reference/type/row-selector#jQuery? I mean smth like this ``var aTags = $('#myTableRowsParent a')`` and then use ``table.rows( aTags ).data()`` ? where under ``myTableRowsParent`` I mean the parent of all ``a`` tags you want to find.

Answer (score 2):

I also think the documentation is a little bit cryptic on that point :) The meaning is

1. By "jQuery selector" there is meant "the jQuery object returned by a $(selector)"
2. Only jQuery objects containing `<tr>`'s is allowed
3. On paginated tables, you must create the "jQuery selector" *before* instantiating the dataTable

So, if you want to pass a jQuery object to a dataTables API instance, that contains all rows where any `<td>` contains the text "test"

```
var selector = $('tr:contains("test")');
var table = $('#example').DataTable();
var rows = table.rows(selector).data();
//now you can iterate 
for (var i=0;i<rows.length;i++) {
    //each rows[i] is an array of the rows columns
    console.dir(rows[i]);
}
```

if you want to pass a jQuery object to a dataTables API instance, that contains all rows where any `<td>` contains an `<a>` containing a certain text, like "test"

```
var selector = $('tr a:contains("test")').parent().parent();
...
var rows = table.rows(selector).data();
...
```

the above selectors in an example -> **http://jsfiddle.net/q2p2n23m/**

Comment: The documentation very clearly states that it takes a string as an argument that it will treat as a jQuery selector. It says nothing about taking a jQuery selector object as an argument. So it's not that the docs are cryptic, they are very simply wrong. Of course, if it's necessary to construct the selector objects before you create the table, then for rows() to take a string from which it would create a jQuery selector would be too late.

Comment: Hey @JeffDege - "_The documentation very clearly states that it takes a string as an argument that it will treat as a jQuery selector_" ..where? It would indeed be the intuitive way, and thats perhaps why we get that false impression. But the text states "**a jQuery instance can be given as a row selector**". I too, think we lack a "pure" `.rows(<selector>)` upportunity!!

Comment: @JeffDege - "_Of course, if it's necessary to construct the selector objects before you create the table, then for rows() to take a string from which it would create a jQuery selector would be too late._" - it is only nessecary when we deal with paginated tables. The reason is, that dataTables removes hidden rows "physically" from the DOM, and then jQuery selectors are to no use if we want to target the <table> as a whole.

Comment: "where"?  On http://datatables.net/reference/type/row-selector read the "When the selector is given as a string ...". I had expected that to work just like passing a jQuery selector, except that it'd find rows that were removed from the DOM.  (We create our tables empty, and populate them via AJAX, so using a jQuery selector woudn't work, anyway.)